# how to find shift in image using cross-correlation in repeating structure image?

Tags: opencv, fft, correlation, cross-correlation, image-preprocessing

For past 2-3 days I am working on a problem for finding shift in repeating structure image. Question is:- repeating structure image is given to us and now I have shifted the image in x direction by some value how to find what was the shift in the image?? Here you can see the image example.
[Repeating structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZot5.jpg)

as you can see the same pattern is repeating in image. I have shifted the image in X direction and tried to find the shift. I have used `register_translation` method for finding the shift in python but I have got wrong result when I am shifting the image by some more pixel. And I know the reason, it happened because of repeating structure in image. I am getting wrong result for smaller shifts also. Now, Can anyone help me how to solve this type of problem or get the answer correct?? Can any one explain how cross correlation handle this type of image?? What extra things I need to do to improve my result? What should I do to solve this problem??
Thank you

Comment: Imho it's impossible without assumptions. How would you solve it as a human?

Comment: "autocorrelation". or run fourier transform and find peaks. you can't remove the ambiguity. live with the ambiguity.