# How to get multiple peak in repeating structure using cross-correlation?

Tags: python, opencv, fft, scikit-image, cross-correlation

I am new to cross-correlation. I am working on images which having many multiple repeating pattern. I want to find shift in the image. I have initial image and then I shifted that image a bit in x and y direction.
For example you can take any repeating pattern image like :- https://depositphotos.com/vector-images/repeat-structure.html.
When I am using `register_translation` for finding shift in image, it's giving me the shift but its wrong. The reason behind is that there are multiple repeating structure in input image.

I want something which can give me multiple peaks after correlation so manually I can correct some code and can find shift in two images correctly. Is there any way to correct the code so that I can get not one but multiple peaks after doing cross-correlation of two images?

code what i did

```
image = cv2.imread('/content/download.jpg',0)
shift = (0,0)
offset_image = fourier_shift(np.fft.fftn(image), shift)
offset_image = np.fft.ifftn(offset_image)
print("Known offset (y, x): {}".format(shift))
shift, error, diffphase = register_translation(image, offset_image)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 3))
ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 2, sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
ax3 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
ax1.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
ax1.set_axis_off()
ax1.set_title('Reference image')
ax2.imshow(offset_image.real, cmap='gray')
ax2.set_axis_off()
ax2.set_title('Offset image')
image_product = np.fft.fft2(image) * np.fft.fft2(offset_image).conj()
cc_image = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.ifft2(image_product))
x=cc_image[0].real
x.sort()
print(x)
ax3.imshow(cc_image.real)
ax3.set_axis_off()
ax3.set_title("Cross-correlation")
plt.show()
```

Here in code if we look at croos-correlation image we can see there are lot of peak if there are repeating pattern in the image. But `register_translation` gives a shift on base of single peak. But there are many other peaks also so how i can get all of them.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [mcve]. Then adapt your post accordingly to meet the stack standard.

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html ?

Comment: @tpk No its template matching here we just do cross correlation and find the peak where  it is maximum. Here we will get only one max peak. But when we use cross-correlation where we want to find shift in image there also we do same thing but functions return us maximum peak. But i want it to return multiple return because there can be multiple matching in image with slight lower peak also. This question is related to how to find shift in image.

Comment: It might be helpful to include since example images.

Comment: @Trilarion you can take any repeating structure image like https://depositphotos.com/vector-images/repeat-structure.html

Comment: key is **local** maxima

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz about which Key you are talking about??

Comment: ignore that word, focus on the rest

Comment: @goodwin, can you share the code that you have done for the single peak? I think as christoph has pointed out, you should modify the code such that it returns local peaks.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yes, but how I can put Local Maxima after doing cross-correlation. How I will decide the value of it. what all factor need to be consider?? how?

Comment: @tpk I have added the code. So python register_translation works on a single peak which is maximum but it gives wrong answer because there can be another peaks also because there are lot of repeating structure. How can i get all the peaks in different places .

Comment: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_peak_local_max.html https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_extrema.html please show some initiative

Comment: and point out if you've asked the same question before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69763670/how-to-find-shift-in-image-using-cross-correlation-in-repeating-structure-image

Comment: See non_max_suppression at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/03/29/multi-template-matching-with-opencv/ or use masking for peak suppression at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67368951/opencv-matchtemplate-and-np-where-keep-only-unique-values/67374288#67374288

Comment: my favorite NMS on raster results is to grayscale-dilate and then compare for equality. not perfect because it doesn't suppress _equal_ maxima, but a lot more elegant than messing around with bboxes before it's necessary. orders of magnitude more sensible than erasing the global maximum and re-scanning.